# Cocoon Callbacks won't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

I've read through other questions and the cocoon github wiki as well, tried out the sample Rails 4 demo (which works) but I can't get the callbacks to fire on my project.

My gem file is a bit long but the most relevant gems IMHO are cocoon from master (1.2.6), thrubyracer, turbolinks, and spring.

form (note that data-no-turbolinks false and true have had no effect):

```
%div{"data-no-turbolink" => "false"}
  = simple_form_for @course, html: { class: "pure-form"} do |f|
    = f.error_notification

    .form-inputs
      = f.input :name, label: false, placeholder: 'Nombre del Curso', html: {id: 'nombre'}

    #subjects.well
      = f.input :materia, collection: @materia, prompt: 'Seleccione una materia', value_method: :name

      = f.input :tema_de_curso, collection: @tema, prompt: 'Seleccione el tema del curso', value_method: :name

      = f.input :grado, collection: @grado, prompt: 'Seleccione el grado', value_method: :name

    #bimesters.well
      = f.simple_fields_for :bimesters do |bimester|
        = render 'bimester_fields', :f => bimester
      .links
        = link_to_add_association 'Agregar Bimestre', f, :bimesters, class: 'btn btn-primary'

    .form-actions
      = f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg'
```

partial:

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :name, collection: @bims, label: 'Bimestre', prompt: 'Seleccione el bimestre', value_method: :name
  = link_to_remove_association 'Eliminar Bimestre', f, class: 'btn btn-danger pull-right', style: 'margin-bottom: 1em; '
```

JS (tried with this extract from the demo project to keep it simple):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bimesters').bind('cocoon:before-insert', function(e,task_to_be_added) {
      console.log(task_to_be_added);
      task_to_be_added.fadeIn('slow');
      task_to_be_added.fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

Relationship is working correctly as well so models and controller should be fine. I've got the sensation that it might be something to do with turbolinks but all tested permutations have failed.

My main goal is to get the id of the elements that have been created because I'm filtering other nested form partials based on these selections.

Comment: Your code seems ok. Are there javascript errors? (check browser console). The `data-no-turbolink` should be declared on the body, to test if it is turbo-link related: refresh the complete page, and check if it works then. Also: instead of using `$(document).ready` also bind to `page:loaded` event.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Hoping you would catch this one. The console is clean, got the data-no-turbolink on the body as well with the page:load event. Just a bit confused with the page:load event suggestion, should I add it like this?  `$(document).on("page:load", function(){}); `. Anyway callbacks are still not firing. I've also got a Spree Commerce app in the project if its of any help.

Comment: Yep, that is just fine. Best to write `$(document).on("ready page:load"), function() {})` to handle both cases.